# Can virtual host is compulsory to create in pwa Magento 2.3.1?

Tags: magento2.3.1, pwa, help-wanted

virtual host  is compulsory to create in pwa Magento 2.3.1 and why please let me know if you have any information

Answer (score 1):

At the moment it is development only. So its virtual only. But as soon as they release hopefully there will be documentation  on deploying to a live site.